# How to determine whether to do an insert or an update on a save operation?

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have problem in profiles pages of users.

I have one table called "profiles" (id,uid,firstname,lastname,state)
when user login in and go to edit profile, he put his informations then agree.

So my script must add his informations to table(profiles) because they are empty! But if the profile has already done, that's mean he look for update his profile not add. I tried to finish this page but it make me feel bad.

```
$profile = sbr_get_user_profile_by_id($uid);
if($profile == NULL)
{
    $result =     sbr_add_profiles($uid,trim($_POST['firstname']),trim($_POST['lastname']),trim($_POST['state']));
    sbr_db_close();
    if($result){
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'success add';
        header('location: modifyProfile.php?id='.$uid);
        die();
     }
     else
         die('no add');
}

$result = sbr_update_profile_users($uid,trim($_POST['firstname']),trim($_POST['lastname']),trim($_POST['state'])));
sbr_db_close();
```

I'm looking for better idea because I don't like this way.

Comment: just use your update function `sbr_update_profile_users` in the `else`, instead of the `die('no add')`..

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Your problem is profile is always added and never updated ?

Comment: _Good code indentation helps in understanding the logic you have coded._ You seem to have started with a good idea i.e. If I can `sbr_get_user_profile_by_id($uid);` then the user already exists. But if you look at the logic you have not followed that through to completion

Comment: Also a suggestion: Use `exit;` instead of `die()` if you are just stopping the script in a gentle manner, only use `die()` in a situation where you want to indicate this is a serious error situation where nothing can be done to recover the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Change your MySQL query. Instead of this:

```
UPDATE table......
```

use this:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,uid,firstname,lastname,state)
VALUES($id,$uid,$firstname,$lastname,$state)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
id=VALUES(id), uid=VALUES(uid), firstname=VALUES(firstname), lastname=VALUES(lastname),state=VALUES(state)
```

You have to set combined Unique key on firstname,lastname in mysql table inorder to get effect of the above query.

By the above query, a new firstname and lastname will be inserted, and if found same firstname and lastname, row will be updated. But as there may be more than one person having same firstname and lastname, you have to set unique key on other columns also, like unique key on firstname,lastname,telephone columns.

I think, in your case, you should set unique key on uid column, if it is different for each users.